# object vs index within .each statements

Tags: jquery, syntax, this, jquery-isotope

I don't think I understand how to get the information I need.

I'm using isotope to layout and sort the divs. *Context: On div click 2 divs of content will be appended and then reSorted into the correct place. I need to add an extra number to divs larger than the current number.*

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows',

    // sort by number
    sortBy: 'number',
    getSortData: {
      'number': '.number parseInt'
    }
  });




  $('.grid-item').click(function(event) {

        $(this).addClass('big');
                $grid.isotope('updateSortData');
        var number = parseInt($(this).find('.number').text(), 10);

        $('.number').each(function(index) {

          var checkNumber = parseInt($(this).text(), 10);

          if (checkNumber > number) {
            $(this).html(checkNumber + 1);
          };

          $grid.isotope('updateSortData');
        });
    }); });
```

What should happen is:

`.grid-item` will be clicked.

It adds the class `.big`

Stores the `.number` as `number`

All of the other `.number` divs check their number `checkedNumber` against the stored number

If `checkNumber` is > than `number` then add `+ 1` to `checkNumber`

https://jsfiddle.net/qg2xndk6/ - not working *Simple version of the above*

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXmjXK - *Larger context* - still not working, but you can see I plan to use AJAX to pull in content and reSort the layout. **You can see after a few clicks the order is wrong**

Thank you for your time and assistance.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: Hi @Mohamed-Yousef simple error checking, but it seems that was enough to get me on the right track. Do you want to make that an answer so I can accept it? 

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPVggZ

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great chance to use event delegation. Rather than attaching the event to each `.grid-item`, you can handle the event when it propagates to the parent container. An optional second argument will allow you to filter based on the element that is clicked:

`$('.grid').on('click', '.grid-item', newclick);`

Now you no longer need to bind the event handler again after adding the new elements.

Other ideas to help troubleshoot the code in you 'pen:

- Ensure you use proper indentation
- Replace your anonymous functions (like in setTimeout calls, callbacks passed to `.each`) with named functions defined higher up in the code. It will make your code much more readable. Like you did with `newclick`!
- Does that `for` loop iterate from 0 to 1? Maybe you don't need it?
- Follow other JS conventions, like camelCase var and function names.